# Eclipse is running my previous .java file not the current one I want to Run

Tags: java, eclipse

I created this ArrayLocation.java yesterday

```
public class ArrayLocation {
    private double coords[];

    public ArrayLocation (double[] coords) {
        this.coords = coords;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double[] coords = {5.0, 0.0};
        ArrayLocation accra = new ArrayLocation (coords);
        coords[0] = 32.9;
        coords[1] = -117.2;
        System.out.println(accra.coords[0]);

    }

} ---This ran well and gave me an output 32.9
```

Today I created a new project and added this MyDisplay.java to it

```
package guimodule;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MyDisplay extends PApplet {

    public void setup(){

        size(400, 600);

    }

    public void draw(){


    }
}
```

But when I run MyDisplay.java eclipse is still running the old ArrayLocation.java and returning 32.9. I expected it would open a blank applet.

Please help. I am pretty new to eclipse

How should I tell eclipse to run MyDisplay.java and not ArrayLocation.java ?

Comment: Your main method still sits in your ArrayLocation class. You might be running this app as a java application which in turn runs your main class from your ArrayLocation class. To Run MyDisplay.java right click on the class and run it as java application.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Projects -> Clean`

Open your java file in the editor, right click `Run as -> Java Application`

Answer (score 0):

There is no main method in your MyDisplay.java.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `BuildAnt`

it will surely help you.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may add main method to MyDisplay.java class itself as follows:

```
package guimodule;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MyDisplay extends PApplet {

    public void setup(){

        size(400, 600);

    }

    public void draw(){


    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
       PApplet.main(new String[] {"guimodule.MyDisplay"});
    }
}
```

OR you can also initiate your MyDisplay.java from other class having main function:

**InitClass.java**

```
public class InitClass{

  public static void main(String args[]){

    final MyDisplay disp = new MyDisplay();
    disp.init();
  }
```